# How to get images to show on a phonegap application

Tags: android, html, css, image, cordova

For the past few months I've been working on a phonegap application for a project I'm involved in, attempting to encourage kids to take an interest in the local history and I've just about finished it but, no matter what I try, I can't get the images to display...

I've been writing the app in HTML/CSS/JS using Brackets and it works fine when I test it using the live debugging thing and Edge Inspect but when it comes to building the app with phonegap, the images just don't display.

The code I used to place the images is:

```
//THE HTML
<img class = "thumbnailImg" src = "img/img1.png">

//THE CSS
.thumbnailImg {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

The folder with the HTML in it is also the folder with the folder of images in it:

> Options (the HTML folder) > all the html files & img (the image folder)

Inside img, the images are indexed with a respective number, 1 through 13.

**EDIT: The file path is above**
[image: file structure of the phonegap application]

If anyone could offer any insight as to why this isn't working, that'd be awesome.

Comment: So you are using the live debugging through Adobe PhoneGap Build?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized you said you were using Edge Inspect. In my app, my code is nearly identical to yours and is working correctly. Try hard coding a height and width in pixels to see if the image displays.

Comment: can you show us the folder structure of the **Asset** directory of you phonegap APP?

Comment: How do I find the asset directory? :S

Comment: Assets directory location for your phonegap App `<your_project_name>\platforms\android\assets`

Comment: Now you have confused me!. The directory structure that you have shown is it the Server side directory or the directory that you have created inside the Phonegap App? Can you tell us the complete process of how you have created your phonegap including the tools used in the process?

Comment: I wrote all the code, the HTML, Javascript, CSS, etc. for the app and then uploaded it to build.phonegap.com where it made the app and generated a QR code which, when scanned will download the app to my phone.  Have I done something wrong?

Comment: This is getting complicated :(. Not able to understand what you have done, but will give it a go. What directory structure did you create and where did you place the HTML,JS,CSS files before uploading the files to the **PhoneGap** build service? You need to create the directory structure similar to one shown by `KRITZE` in the answer starting with `www` folder and then ZIP the file and upload to the `build.phonegap.com'. I will try to explain it in the answer section, as the comments is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blagged a fix by putting a div where the image would be and just setting the background to the image.  Not sure why it wasn't working but this seems to have fixed it so yeah.  Yay.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your folder structure looks like below,

[image: Make]
This should work fine, Please check the image extension of "img1". Right click on the image file and see properties and check "Type of file:" and verify it is really a .png file.

Comment: I've added my file structure.  It's essentially the same as the one you uploaded but the folders have different names.

Comment: How do I see the edit?  I'm kind of new to using stackoverflow so I'm not entirely sure about all the stuff on it :/

Comment: Sorry my quiver is empty. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Let say your project name is 'My_first_PG_App'.
Assume that you have the following resource files for your app.

**HTML files**
1) Index.html ( This file is a must. This is the starting point of your PG App).

**Image files**
1) img1.png

**CSS files**
1) my_first_pg_app.css

Then you need to create the following directory structure and place the files at the appropriate location.

```
+My_first_PG_App <directory>
         |__ index.html
         |__ config.xml
         |__img <directory>
             |__ img1.png
         |__css <directory>
             |__ my_first_pg_app.css
```

Then zip the `My_first_PG_App` directory and upload the zip file to the build.phonegap.com

you can now access the resources e.g **img1.png** in your **index.html** as

```
<img class = "thumbnailImg" src = "img/img1.png">
```

**EDIT1:**

You can also have a look of the phonegap build tutorial over here.
https://helpx.adobe.com/phonegap-build/how-to/phonegap-build-first-app.html?set=phonegap-build--get-started--ready-to-use

Comment: Okay, my file structure is like this then:

PBHQ: GO WEST <Directory>
    |__index.html
    |__options <Directory>
          |__option1.html
          |__option2.html
          |__and so on
    |__css <Directory>
          |__styles.css
          |__buttons.css
          |__photoswipe <Directory>
                |__all the photoswipe stuff
    |__js
          |__fastclick.js
          |__index.js
          |__iScroll.js
          |__jQuery2.0.3.js
          |__menu.js
          |__tauthorization.js

I don't have a config.xml file.  Might that be why the images aren't working properly?

Comment: Well that didn't work.  I'll edit the main post to show it properly.